# Google Search Console couldn't fetch my XML Sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, asp.net

I have an asp.net web form project.
For creating a sitemap on this project, I didn't use a regular asp.net  `Web.sitemap` file in Visual Studio, like by doing:

> menu File --> New File --> Web.sitemap from Visual Studio.

Instead I used the web site below for creating sitemap:
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com

Here is my created sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Shop.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Default.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Activate_Your_Cards.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Check_Card_Balance.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/How_To_Buy_Bitcoin_With_CoinMama_Worldwide.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/How_To_Buy_Bitcoin_In_Less_Than_5_Minutes.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/What_Is_Escrow_Protection_How_Does_Escrow_Work.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Our_Team.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/About_VirtualVisaCards_Site.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Where_To_Use_Virtual_Visa_Cards.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Privacy_Policy.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Term_Of_Service.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/FAQs.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Contact_Us.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Products/Silver_Virtual_Visa_Card.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Products/Gold_Virtual_Visa_Card.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/Products/Platinum_Virtual_Visa_Card.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/billionaire_mark_cuban_i_see_gold_and_bitcoin_as_being_the_same_thing.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/what_are_virtual_credit_cards_and_should_you_have_one.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/stay_secure_online_with_virtual_credit_card_numbers.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/credit_not_as_great_as_you_would_like.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/all_you_want_to_know_about_emv_chip_cards.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/want_something_secured.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://mysite.info/CheckOut.aspx</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-12T13:38:02+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>


</urlset>
```

And here you can validate my sitemap:
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html
Here's my sitemap URL:
`https://mysite.info/sitemap.xml`
You can see everything is OK about my sitemap.
Now when I submit my sitemap to Google Search Console it reports:

> couldn't fetch

[image: couldn't fetch sitemap - Google Search Console error]
Is this a Google bug?
What did I do wrong & how can I fix this error?
For multiple sites I got this error.

---

**PS :**
For another web site I have this issue too.
I waited 1 month - but the error is still there.

---

**Edit**
I cleared IIS logs & here is the log after introduce my sitemap to Google.

> Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
>   Version: 1.0
>   Date: 2020-01-12 15:35:16
>   Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
>   time-taken 2020-01-12 15:35:16 176.9.199.136 GET /sitemap.xml - 80 -
>   172.68.51.35 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64;+rv:71.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/71.0
>   304 0 0 78 2020-01-12 15:35:27 176.9.199.136 GET /sitemap.xml - 80 -
>   141.101.99.168 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+XML+Sitemaps+Generator;+www.xml-sitemaps.com)+Gecko+XML-Sitemaps/1.0
>   200 0 0 33

As you see google did n't make a request to my machine at all.
I am so confused about that.

Comment: Have you tried creating sitemaps with any other site?
Also test if this sitemap is working on bing webmaster tools?

Comment: @couponhero I tried it at this moment. It tells Success & there is no problem about bing.

Comment: Try <urlset> as the first tag instead of what you have

Comment: It is pointless to generate a sitemap by crawling your site.  Googlebot is able to crawl your site just as readily as any sitemap generator.  [Google Says Don't Crawl Your Site To Build A Sitemap File](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-dont-crawl-your-site-sitemap-file-28453.html)

Comment: Why downvote? It's an important issue.

Comment: I explained my down vote.  It doesn't matter if if Google can read your sitemap or not.  You generated the sitemap by crawling your site.